# Using python I need to transfer documents from Azure CosmosDB with MongoDB api to Postrgres on a daily basis probably using Azure functions

Tags: python, mongodb, postgresql, azure

How can I efficiently transfer newly arrived documents from Azure CosmosDb with MongoDb api to Postgres at regular intervals?

I am thinking of using a python script to query MongoDB based on timedate, but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: This question could use more focus: 

It seems like you have already decided to have a periodically running Python script to do the transfer. If that is the case, then focus the question more: all you need to know is how to query MongoDb for documents where a field contains a timestamp within a given range. (This isn't an Azure or a Postgresql question.)

OTOH, if you haven't decided on your architecture yet, then just ask how to efficiently transfer newly arrived documents from AzureCosmosDB to Postgres.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Data Factory to achieve this. Use Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API as source and Postgres as sink. Then use watermark to record your last modify time. Finally, create a schedule trigger to execute it.